# preg match, replace url to bbcode

Tags: php, regex, bbcode

i write preg match rules:

```
$subject = 'text  <a href="http://google.com">LINK</a> text text <a href="http://google2.com">LINK2</a>';

$search = array(
    '/\<a href\="(.*)\">(.*)\<\/a\>/i'
);

$replace = array(
    "[a href=\"$1\"]$2[/a]"
);

echo preg_replace($search, $replace, $subject);
```

When in text only one link everything works great, then more then one - crach code

This i get when is more than one link:
"text [a href="http://google.com">LINK text text "

Answer (score 2):

Change to `'/\<a href\="(.*?)\">(.*?)\<\/a\>/i'` to make the matching not-**greedy**.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a better regex - it deals with extra fields in the  tags:

```
 \<a (?:.*?)href\=[\"\']([^\"\']+?)[\"\'][^\>]*?\>(.+?)\<\/a\>
```

I think I've escaped all of the special characters in there, I'm not sure what PHP considers 'special', but basically this should match all of the following:

```
 $subject = 'text  <a id="test" href="http://google.com">LINK</a> text text <a href="http://google2.com" id="test">LINK2</a> text <a href="http://google3.com">LINK3</a>';
```

Also, I don't know about PHP, but to match more than one link in Perl, you need the /g modifier on the end of that regex, so:

```
 $search = array(
      '/\<a (?:.*?)href\=[\"\']([^\"\']+?)[\"\'][^\>]*?\>(.+?)\<\/a\>/ig'
 );
```

would be your search. Maybe preg_replace does this already, but I'd be surprised, since there are times when you'd only want to replace one instance in your target text.